# Thrift generates raw type in AsyncIface

Tags: java, thrift

With Thrift 0.9.1 and maven-thrift-plugin 0.1.11, for every method in my `service Voigy` (e.g. `CandidateAnswer getAnswers(1:Query query) throws (1:VoigyException e)`) I see something like

```
public void getAnswers(Query query, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;
```

in `Voigy.AsyncIface` instead of `AsyncMethodCallback<CandidateAnswer>` which I expected. Is this the intended result, known bug in Thrift or maven-thrift-plugin, or a problem with my setup?

`Voigy.thrift`:

```
namespace java com.voigy.api

struct Query {
  1: required i32 scriptNodeId
  2: required string text
}

struct Parameter {
  1: required i32 paramTypeId
  2: required i32 startIndex
  3: required i32 endIndex
  4: required string normalizedText
}

struct CandidateAnswer {
  1: required i32 classifierId
  2: required list<Parameter> parameters
}

exception VoigyException {
  1: required string message
  2: required i32 errorCode
}

service Voigy {
  CandidateAnswer getAnswers(1:Query query) throws (1:VoigyException e)

  void startLearning(1:i32 scriptNodeId, 2:bool force) throws (1:VoigyException e)

  void startLearningParameters(1:bool force) throws (1:VoigyException e)

  void startLearningAll(1:bool force) throws (1:VoigyException e)
}
```

I don't know how to see exact command line used by maven-thrift-plugin, but looking at code, this should be something like `C:\thrift\thrift -r --gen java -out target/generated-sources/thrift **/*.thrift` (and this reproduces the same result).

Comment: Looking at `ServerTestBase.java` it seems to be the expected outcome. I don't know the background, though.  Maybe you want to ask this on the mailing list.

Comment: See this comment on the original patch: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1972?focusedCommentId=13659623&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13659623